# Understanding Elliptic Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition

I don't have a strong background in partial differential equations so some of these questions might be quite basic. I first want to give some definitions which I am using.

**Definition**:

We define a second-order elliptic partial differential equation:

$Au_{xx}+2Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_{x}+Eu_{y}+F=0$ where $B^{2}-AC<0$. Assuming $u_{xy} = u_{yx}$.

We define a uniformly elliptic operator in the following way:

**Definition:**

A partial differential operator $L$ is (uniformly) elliptic if there exists a constant $\theta>0$ such that $\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}a^{i,j}(x)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} \geq \theta|\xi|^{2}$

for a.e. $x \in U$ and all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

1.What is the connection between elliptic operators and elliptic partial differential equations?
2.What is the importance of this property $\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}a^{i,j}(x)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} \geq \theta|\xi|^{2}$ which is used in the definition of uniformly elliptic operators above? 
3.Do uniformly elliptic operators always give you a linear partial differential equation?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21525/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/878746/532409

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The constant matrix $a = (a^{i,j}) = \left[\begin{matrix} A & B \\ B & C \end{matrix}\right]$ satisfies the ellipticity condition if and only if $A>0$ and $AC-B^2>0$.  For $n\times n$ matrices, the ellipticity condition is saying that $a$ is positive definite uniformly over $x$.  And one criterion for positive definite is that the determinants of the $k\times k$ upper left hand corner matrices all have positive determinant.  Note in the $2\times2$ case, the condition $A>0$ is not so important, because if $A<0$ you can simply multiply the whole equation by $-1$.
2. Ellipticity conditions are important because they guarantee uniqueness of solutions (although usually with other more benign hypotheses).  This is a huge subject.  I would recommend the book "Maximum Principles in Differential Equations" by Murray H. Protter, Hans F. Weinberger as a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you explain how we show that the elliplicity condition implies that the matrix $a = ((a^{i,j}(x)))$ is positive definite. The definition of positive definite that I am familiar with states that an $nxn$ matrix $M$ is positive definite if $Z^{T}MZ$  is positive for any nonzero column transpose of $Z$.

Comment: This is a uniform bound on the positive definiteness.  So what we have is that $M-\theta I$ is positive definite for some $\theta>0$.  And this results in $z^T M z \ge \theta z^T z = \theta |z|^2$.

Comment: Okay but how does $M-\theta I$ is positive definite follow from the elliplicity condition? Just to confirm, for the rest of the calculation you are saying $Z^{T}(M-\theta I)Z = Z^{T}MZ-Z^{T}\theta Z > 0$ $\therefore$ $Z^{T}MZ \geq \theta Z^{T}Z = \theta |Z|^{2}$

Comment: Another equivalent condition for a symmetric matrix $M$ to be positive definite is that all its eigenvalues are positive.  Let $\theta$ be the minimum of all the eigenvalues.  Then $M-\theta I$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: I still don't see how this follows from  $\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}a^{i,j}(x)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} \geq \theta|\xi|^{2}$? How do you go from this to stating $a = ((a^{i,j}))$ is positive definite?

Comment: I you mean the reverse implication?  That condition says $z^T M z \ge \theta|z|^2$.  And $\theta|z|^2 > 0$.  By the way, I don't think the upper limit in the sum should be infinity - it should be $n$.  I think that is a typo.

Comment: Yes it's a typo thanks. I'm looking for a line of reasoning which starting with the elliplicity condition  $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a^{i,j}(x)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} \geq \theta|\xi|^{2}$ and then showing that it follows from this assumption that $a$ is positive definite. Sorry if these questions are basic, I have only recently started studying PDE's.

Comment: If I write $M = (a^{i,j})$, then $z^T M z = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{i,j} z_i z_j$.

Comment: I understand, thanks for all of your responses.