# how to tell the types of higher order partial differential equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, hyperbolic-equations, parabolic-pde

I'm reading P42 on Robert C. Rogers' book *"An introduction to partial differential equations"* , and I found the way he classifies higher order PDEs a little confusing, especially when it comes to hyperbolic and parabolic ones.

For example, I know  $u_{xxxx}-u_{xxyy}+u_{yyyy}=0$ is elliptic since $L^p$ (the principal part) = $\xi^4-\xi^2\eta^2+\eta^4 = 0$ is only possible when $(\xi,\eta)=(0,0)$.

But for this equation $u_{tt}+u_{xxxx}=0$, the principal part $L^p = \xi^4 = 0$ means that $(\xi,\eta)=(0, \eta)$, for all $\eta\in \mathbb{R}$. Does it make this equation parabolic?

Another question: Can we always classify higher order PDEs as parabolic, hyperbolic or elliptic?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21525/mathematical-precise-definition-of-a-pde-being-elliptic-parabolic-or-hyperbolic/21540#21540)

Comment: @Artem thank you! this clarifies a lot! But I'm still confused about the second equation in my post. If I follow what is said in that article, then for no $\tau$ will the polynomial in s, $(\xi + s\tau)^4=0$ have 4 distinct real roots. So it's neither elliptic nor strictly hyperbolic, right?

Comment: How did you obtain the principle part for the first equation? I was able to do it for part a in the same book. I guess where I'm stuck is obtaining the matrix form

Comment: In the text, they explain how to obtain the principal part for second order PDE. I'm so confused on how to do it for higher order PDE, the formulation I can't find on google