# Type Classification of a higher order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, hyperbolic-equations, parabolic-pde

So here’s my higher order PDE, $u_{xxxx}-u_{xxyy}+u_{yyyy}=0$. I’m trying classify this as either elliptic or strictly hyperbolic. It is elliptic if there are no real characteristics at $\vec{x}$ otherwise it is hyperbolic. Thanks for the help, hints are welcome

Update: So consider another equation, $u_{xy}+2u_x=0$. I think I got solution for this right.

$Lu=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\implies b(x,y)=1$ and $d(x,y)=2$.

$\implies L^p(x,y,i\xi,i\eta)=-\xi\eta=(\xi,\eta)\begin{pmatrix}0&-1/2\\-1/2&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\xi\\\eta\end{pmatrix}$. So since eigenvalues of the matrix are real and equal then it is definite. Therefore, it is elliptic

Update: this might be useful

Here are definitions from book,

Def: Let L be an operator of the form $L(\vec{x},D)u=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_\alpha(\vec{x})D^\alpha u$ where $D^{\alpha}=\frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\partial x_2^{\alpha_2} ...\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}$. Here, $|\alpha|=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n$. Characteristic surfaces`are defined by equation, $L^p(\vec{x},\nabla\phi)=0$.

An equation is **elliptic** at $\vec{x}$ if there are no real charactersitics at $\vec{x}$, that is, $L^p(\vec{x},i\vec{\xi})\neq 0, \forall \vec{\xi}\neq 0$.

An equation is **strictly hyperbolic** in direction $\vec{n}$ if

$1.\ L^p(\vec{x},i\vec{n})\neq 0$

$2.$ all the roots $\omega$ of the equation,   $L^p(\vec{x},i\vec{\xi}+i\omega\vec{n})=0 $, are real and distinct $\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not collinear with $n$

Comment: The classification "elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic" is just for second order PDE.

Comment: Not sure about that, not according to the book at least

Comment: [inline link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244129/how-to-tell-the-types-of-higher-order-partial-differential-equations). this question has been asked before, but I have no idea how they obtained the principal part. That's what I'm having trouble with, after finding this out, the classification is pretty straight forward